# How/where can I get people to tell me their personal reactions to my work?

Tags: feedback, audience-reaction, personal-bias

The book I'm writing is memoir, journalism, social critique, diatribe, autoethnography -- accounts of personal experience, research to help me understand, reflection, analysis of social factors, opinion, witnessing, speaking out, howl....

It would embarrass my family, and possibly subject me to harassment.  So I'm using a pseudonym, and as a result I know few people I can talk to about my work. I want to ask readers what they think of the book, what they think of the ideas in the book. I don't mean technical advice or critiquing -- rather how they react to reading it, what it means to them.

Recently I've joined a few writers' support groups and posted the URL of the online book. I hoped to get personal reactions. I got very, very little response.

I've talked to three friends I can trust to keep confidentiality. One has been very helpful.

Comment: Keep in mind that just using a pseudonym provides very little protection against determined people finding out who you are if you use lots of facts in the book. (e.g. which school you went to, which employers you worked for.)

Comment: If you need someone to look over your work, I'll help point you in a good direction. Send me a link or here's my email. FootedSleet8505@gmail.com /I enjoy looking over work/ It'll take me at least a few days to get back to this.

Comment: Try CritiqueCircle on line.